# How to get Tomcat Working on WIndows 7?

Tags: apache, tomcat, windows-7, webserver

I have installed Apache Tomcat 5.X/6.X on my Winodws 7 PC. After the installaiton the service starts fine when I check the Start Tomcat box and click finish. However If I try to start the tomcat configuration tool or monitor tool from the start menu I can not start any of the Tomcat's services. I get an error in a message box stating "Access Deined. Unable to open Tomcat 5.5". What seems to be the problem? and How can I solve it? Even restarting the PC won't help. I also have JDK and JRE installed. Turing the firewall doesn't work too. Please Help! Note that I'm running 32bit Version of Windows 7.

Comment: Have you try to start your application as root user?

Answer (score 1):

You must "Run as an Administrator" to start the tomcat configuration tool or monitor tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tomcat 6.0, you should have Java 6.0 or above version installed in your system. Try this, it definitely works. If you have any issues feel free to revert me.